# Ansible for Juniper on Ubuntu 20.04 - interpreter error

Tags: networking, 20.04, ansible

I'm having trouble setting up my Ansible playbook to run for Juniper on Ubuntu 20.04. I works for cisco though .
At this point I'm stuck at getting Python 3 to work as the interpreter. Any working solutions will be most appreciated. I've checked Google, GitHub, Ansible and the Ubuntu documentation, but none of them solved my problem (or maybe I just couldn't find the right solution). See the error message below.

```
*****fatal: [Ikeja]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python3.8.5: not found\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "The module failed to execute correctly, you probably need to set the interpreter.\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 127}*****
```

I've edited the interpreter in multiple locations for both Python 3 and 3.8 without luck. See below.

```
---Hostfile--
[junos]
Ikeja ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
Uyo
[junos:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
---Ansible cofig file ( /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg )------
[defaults]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
----- .bashrc file ------
alias python="/usr/bin/python3"
root@treadstone:~# ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python3 <-------- This is blue all others below are green
/usr/bin/python3.8
/usr/bin/python3-futurize
/usr/bin/python3-pasteurize
/usr/bin/python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script3
/usr/bin/python-argcomplete-tcsh3
```

Comment: I don't known ansible that well but it works on my 20.04 - I have python3 installed and also the apt package "python-is-python3" which makes python point to python3

Comment: then again, I have these pythons in my /usr/bin :   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root            7 apr 15  2020 python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root            9 mrt 13  2020 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root      3629032 aug  4 13:16 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root            9 jan  4 19:19 python3 -> python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root      5486352 jul 28 14:59 python3.8

Comment: it seems python3.8.5 is being serached in /usr/bin - no idea why - one "not very nice" solution would be to create a link in /usr/bin/python3.8.5 to point to python3.8  -- the correct solution would be to find out where this 3.8.5 comes from

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer to  fix the issue : script looking for /usr/bin/python3.8.5 could be

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s python3 python3.8.5
```

this will make a link "python3.8.5" in /usr/bin which points to /usr/bin/python3

not really a clean solution

a better solution could be to change the script that searches for python3.8.5 to just search for python3 or python3.8 - but I have no idea where this 3.8.5 comes from

Comment: Thanks Koen .. Will try your ( sudo ln -s python3 python3.8.5 ) suggestion & revert. Though Ive also tried pointing to python3 , python3.8 ..even installed python2.7 & pointed to it without result

Comment: Note my Ansible playbook works fine for cisco devices